# Comparing two tables to see for any change in column in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

There is table with values of employee and their middle name

```
ID FIRST NAME    MIDDLE NAMES

1  'ABC'          
2  'Jck'           w
3   'Zoya'         A
```

Now there is another table B with some values

```
ID FIRST NAME    MIDDLE NAMES   Flag

    4  'XYZ'          
    2  'Jck'           
    1   'ABC'         A
```

Now  i want to check in table B that if the middle names in B is same as that of table A. that is middle name exists in table A and not B against the same employee number or vice versa then THE Flag should be returned as 'N'

I am using the query :

```
update table b
set flag='N'
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TABLE B
WHERE B.MIDDLE_NAMES=A.MIDDLE_NAME
AND ID=A.ID)
```

Comment: What are you using an `update` if you want to return a value?  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: i want to set the flag as 'N' when there are any discrepency in the middlenames in the two table for a particular employee

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery should have more conditions than just the middle name. Currently, the subquery only checks middle name, so if a person in table A has a middle name that occurs *anywhere* in table B, then you have a match, even if it is for a different person.

To find the employees in A that don't have a matching middle name in B, the query could look like this:

```
select
  a.ID
from
  TableA a
where
  not exists (
    select 'x'
    from 
      TableB b
    where
      b.ID = a.ID and
      b.MIDDLE_NAMES = a.MIDDLE_NAMES);
```

You can use that same query in an update:

```
update TableA a
set
  a.flag = 'N'
where
  a.ID in (
    select
      a.ID
    from
      TableA a
    where
      exists (
        select 'x'
        from 
          TableB b
        where
          b.ID = a.ID and
          b.MIDDLE_NAMES = a.MIDDLE_NAMES));
```

The update can probably be a little simpler, but the advantage of use a whole query like this, is that you can easily check its output without actually updating records. It makes developing, testing and debugging a lot easier.